# How to control the order of inherited columns in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have augmented the Base class so it creates the columns used in all tables in my project. However, I would like to control the order of the columns when creating the tables in the database so that the `DWH_ID` column is the first column in the table and all other columns created in the Base class are last columns of the table.

Let's say that my project is defined as follows:

```py
from sqlalchemy import CHAR, Column, create_engine, DateTime, Integer, Text
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

class Base:

    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'some_schema'}

    dwh_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, comment='Surrogate key')
    dwh_date_inserted = Column(DateTime(timezone=False), default=func.now(), nullable=False, comment='Date and time when the record has been inserted')
    dwh_date_updated = Column(DateTime(timezone=False), nullable=True, comment='Date and time when the record has been updated')
    dwh_is_active = Column(CHAR(1), default='Y', nullable=False, comment="'Y' if the record is still available in the source, 'N' otherwise")

engine = create_engine(SOME_CONNECTION_STRING)
Base = declarative_base(cls=Base)

class Person(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'persons'

    first_name = Column(Text(), nullable=False, comment="First name of the person")
    last_name = Column(Text(), nullable=False, comment="Last name of the person")

Base.metadata.create_all(engine, checkfirst=True)
engine.dispose()
```

The created table looks like this:

```
dwh_id | dwh_date_inserted | dwh_date_updated | dwh_is_active | first_name | last_name
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want this order of columns:

```
dwh_id | first_name | last_name | dwh_date_inserted | dwh_date_updated | dwh_is_active
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I couldn't find anything helpful in the documentation. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why do you care about the order of the columns in the db? Is there a specific use case?

Comment: @jen Just a personal preference. Tables I use are quite large and I would prefer important columns first when using SELECT * FROM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sqlalchemy 2.0+ you can easy do it with the `sort_order` parameter of `mapped_column`.

[SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapped_column.params.sort_order)